# regexp if start with \{ or \"

Tags: regex, tcl

I'm trying to write a regular expression that test if a variable start with a string character in TCL, I wrote this code but it doesn't work

```
if {[regexp {^\"\{.*} $data]} {puts "something" }
```

*string char in TCL starts with { or "

Comment: Hey I don't know TCL so that may be normal, but haven't you forgotten to close your `[` ?

Comment: hey thank you I edited it @Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pick the right regular expression and use it correctly. This can get a lot less confusing if you store the RE in a variable first, particularly with large regular expressions, but even in this case it helps you understand the difference between the literal RE and how it is used.

```
set RE {^[\"\{]}
if {[regexp $RE $theString]} {
    puts "something"
}
```

Note that Tcl does not anchor its RE matching by default, so you don't need a leading or trailing `.*` if you are *just* determining if a RE matches.

Comment: Hey @Donal I tried it but it didn't work, am I missing something? 

`% set theString "hello"
hello
% set RE {^[\"\{]}
^[\"\{]
% if {[regexp $RE $theString]} {puts "true"} else {puts "false"}
false
%`

Comment: @RehamJf: you are missing that the quote characters aren't part of the string. Your variable contains the characters h e l l o only.

Comment: @PeterLewerin  Oh! actually my code is to reading from a text file and check if the line is start with a string character, i thought in this regexp way to check that but it looks isn't a good idea!!  any help to do that in another way?

Comment: @RehamJf: if you are reading from a file you won't have this problem. Any quote characters in the file will appear in the variable you are reading into.

Comment: @PeterLewerin Thank you very much!